# Served HTML Table does not change content without restarting server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been having this issue for a while and have searched around for an answer, sadly I have yet to find one. So, I am asking the questions myself.

The problem is this:
[image: website pre update]

In my database I only have one game that is not marked as finished. Which should be updated on the webpage when I refresh, but it's not. I don't really understand why this is happening as I am quite new to web development. I would appreciate any help you, guys, can give me. If you need any further info, don't hesitate to ask for it.

Raw Page Code

```
<title>CoinFlip</title>
<style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;}th, td {padding: 15px;}</style>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Game Title</th>
<th>Buyin</th>
<th>return</th>
<th>finished</th>
<th>User1</th>
<th>User2</th>
<th>User1 Choice</th>
<th>Join</th>
</tr>
{coinflip_table_data}
</table>
<h2>Logged in as {name}</h2><h1><a href="/logout">Logout</a></h2>
```

Code used to edit the page content
[image]

Code used to send the page content
[image: code used to send the page content]

Picture of database content

[image: Database content]

Thanks again for helping out! :D

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(matches)` ?

Comment: I get the correct amount of matches. So for the example above, it outputs Match amount: 1 but displays 2 matches on the page.@Neverever

Comment: cool, let's do this step by step, what do you get when `console.log(coinflip_table_data)`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7Zt6dKdM That's the message i receive, which is the correct information and everything. @Neverever

Comment: omg, I'm really stupid. I changed to source, so it never replaced the content with the new data. This was just me being stupid. It's fixed now. Thanks anyways for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was editing the source file and not copying it and sending the copied version. So the file never had any of the placeholders that get replaced when I tried to send the updated data.